# Could a President choose to give an existing SCOTUS Justice two votes when he would ordinarily appoint another justice?

Tags: united-states, us-supreme-court, us-president

Could a President actually give a current Supreme Court Justice two votes when another justice died or resigned, as described in [this Babylon Bee article](https://babylonbee.com/news/trump-decides-to-just-give-clarence-thomas-two-votes), except with the consent of the Senate (that article implies that Trump gave Justice Thomas two votes without a Senate confirmation in)?

UPDATE: I know the article is satire.

Comment: I don't think that is a credible source at all that this could even be possible. I would rank it about as credible as ["Der Postillion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Postillon) - a satire paper in Germany. In fact, [Babylon Bee IS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Babylon_Bee) a " a conservative Christian **news satire**", so anything they write is pretty much bovine excrement that is pointed to make you laugh.

Comment: @Trish as i mentioned in the comments on jwh20's answer, I know Babylon Bee is satire. This question was asking if their hypothetical scenario that obviously didn't happen could actually happen, and the answer appears to be no (which is what I expected).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, as noted in the comments, Babylon Bee is SATIRE.  It's not intended to be news, just entertainment.

But the real question is whether or not a President COULD do such a thing.  Or perhaps better, could a President attempt to do something like this.

If a President did attempt to do this, it would be totally without precedent and also without any constitutional authority.  Since the US Constitution enumerates the powers between the branches and gives the President only the authority to appoint, with the advice of the Senate, a SCOTUS justice, trying to change things by giving an existing justice 2 votes would almost certainly be immediately challenged by the Senate.  It also seems unlikely that such an action would be upheld as constitutional.

Of course this is all speculative since nothing of this nature has happened.

Comment: Yes, I know Babylon Bee is satire. I was just curious if a President could actually do this.